# Is this exception due to garbage collection?

Tags: c#, user-interface, garbage-collection, unity-game-engine

I got a strange exception at line 89 of the following code:

```
    private byte   state = 0;
    .
    .
    .

    void OnGUI(){
    int i;
    GUI.skin = skin;
    GUI.skin.box.fontSize = 25;
    GUI.skin.label.fontSize = 18;
    if(state==0){           
        GUI.skin.font = system;
        GUIContent tA = new GUIContent("A");
        Vector2 tz = GUI.skin.label.CalcSize(tA);
        GUI.skin.label.CalcHeight(tA,tz.x);
        height = (byte) tz.y;
        rows   = (byte) (Screen.height/height);
        mark   = 0;
70      view   = new Log[rows];
        for(i=0;i<rows;i++){
72          view[i] = new Log();
            if(vis.ValidRow()){
74              mark++;
75              view[i].time = vis.time;
76              view[i].descrip = vis.descrip;
                vis.Next();
            }
        }
        state = 1;
    }

    GUI.skin.font = chrome;
    GUI.Box(new Rect(0,0,Screen.width,50),"Server");
    GUI.color = Color.green;
    GUI.skin.font = system;
    short y = 50;
    for(i=0;i<mark;i++){
89      GUI.Label(new Rect(10,y,200,height),String.Format("{0:yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss}",view[i].time));
        GUI.Label(new Rect(220,y,Screen.width-260,height),view[i].descrip);
        y += height;
    }
}
```

**System.NullReferenceExeption** is thrown, caused due to ***view*** being null, but I just can't figure out why. All variables have the correct value except for ***view***. In this case ***state*** is **1**, which means the code inside the **if** was executed, ***mark*** is **3**, which means lines: *70*, *72* and *74* were executed without problem. If for some reason **new** would've failed at line *70*, the exception would've been thrown at line *72*. Am I right?... But lines *75* and *76* were also executed without problem.

The only reasonable explanation I can find for this behavior is that ***view*** was garbage collected, but can't understand why... and if that's the case, how can I keep ***view*** from being garbage collected?

**EDIT:**

There is no other place in the program where ***state*** is set to **1** nor any other value. ***view*** is never set to **null** anywhere in the program. What you see is the whole functional code, I only removed variable declarations and initialization, none of which touches either ***state*** nor ***view***. Both ***state*** and ***view*** are declared **private**.

This code is a test project I'm doing in **Unity**.

**EDIT:**

This is not a fixed problem, it happens only once in a while, and it seems there is some kind of timing involved, since until now I have been completely unable to repeat this problem with the debugger on.

Comment: `state` being `1` is not enough evidence to say the code in the if-block has run. The problem is either somewhere else is setting `state` or some other code is setting `view` to null.

Comment: @lc somewhere else? where? ectoplasmic code? Except for the variable declarations, and some initialization via Awake, this is pretty much the whole program, there is no other place where state becomes 1 nor there is a view=null, that is why I posted this question in the first place.

Comment: I'm 99% sure none of this has to do with garbage collection, but can you post the code of `Label`?

Comment: @lc I cannot post that code because it is part of Unity, it is internal, I don't have access to it.

Comment: If `view` is defined outside of the `OnGUI` method, then it isn't being garbage collected. If it's `null`, then either it was never set, or it's being set to `null` by something else. I doubt it's "ectoplasmic code." You're *certain* that no other code modifies any of those variables? If not, then why are they declared at class scope instead of within the `OnGUI` method?

Comment: Put a breakpoint there and check the value.  Is `view` null or is `view[i]` null?  In fact, there is so little code you should be able to step through each line of code and watch the value of view as you go to see what is happening as you progress through the code.

Comment: Is this an editor script (which would explain the strangeness) or a normal script you put in a game obejct in the scene?

Comment: @JimMischel my reference to "ectoplasmic code" was sarcastic. I know the is something on my code causing the problem, but what you see above is the only working code, the rest is just variable declarations and some initialization of extrernal dll's which runs only once and before any call to this function is made. NO MORE CODE EXISTS!!!.

Comment: @JohnKoerner it is not a fixed problem, it happens only once in a while and it seem like there is some kind of timing involved, since applying break points seems to set aside the problem.

Comment: @pek this is a normal script, declared as: `public class Server : MonoBehaviour`

Comment: Yeah, I can't figure out what's wrong. I tried to copy this functionality by writing this: http://pastebin.com/3RyDGijh That code works fine. How different, functionally, is it from yours?

Comment: @pek Except for some details that have nothing to do with `view` the code you posted is basically what I have. In my case, the problems occurs only once in a while, about 1 out every 20 runs, but the problem seems to correct itself by setting up a break point anywhere inside the `if`, remove the break point and the problem arises again. Why? I just cannot understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't know why this problem happened, and probably never will. I modified **OnGUI** so the **if** is rather controlled by ***view==null*** instead of ***state==0***, this way if for some strange reason ***view*** becomes **null** it is restored.

Comment: I'd suggest you continue to debug to find the root cause of your issues. Not understanding your own code is a recipe for disaster.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, mark is counting HOW MANY array slots have values, while the index by which they're assigned is I. So, this is one scenario that can happen:

null, null, null, 1, null, 0, 2

where mark is 3, and rows is 7. Your second for counts to mark, accessing the first three null elements.

I know you're setting every entry in the array to new Log(), but this is a very valid logical error. Also, maybe the object which is null is not view OR view[I], but rather view[I].time? Do a line-by-line trace of the code and we'll know for sure.

Comment: The problem is not: `view[i]==null`, the problem is: `view==null`, just as if line 70 wasn't executed, but if line 70 wasn't executed then how do you explain `mark>0` and `state==1`??? and if `new` failed, how do you explain no exception was thrown at line 72??? The only logical explanation I can find for that is a garbage collection problem.

Comment: If you read carefully you will realize this problem, as far and as hard as I've tested does not happen when there is an active break point, so until today I have been unable to trace the program, reason for which I posted this question.

Comment: I have MonoDevelop setup to break on exceptions, I've checked all variables when the exception occurs and all of them have the correct values, except for `view` which is `null`, that is: `view==null`.

Comment: I don't see your code checking for state == 1 anywhere. As for mark, i have no idea. Can you post the entire code here? This exception of yours has got me seriously curious!